# TransactionScope/USEROPTIONS Isolation discrepancy

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, transactions

What happens if there is a discrepancy between the isolation level used in SQL Server and the isolation level in System.Transactions.TransactionScope.

For example, please consider this scenario: TransactionScope.IsolationLevel returns READ COMMITTED and DBCC USEROPTIONS (executed in SQL Studio Manager) returns READ UNCOMMITTED.

I have tested this and it appears that the setting in USEROPTIONS stands i.e. other VB.NET clients are able to execute SELECT statements (selecting "dirty" data) whilst the VB.NET transaction scope is in progress if the transaction scope isolation level is READ COMMITTED and the USEROPTIONS isolation level is uncommitted.

I cannot find any reference material from MSDN that confirms this.  Can anyone confirm that this is the behavior or point me to an MSDN reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/05/24/sql-server-check-the-isolation-level-with-dbcc-useroptions.

The useroptions command returns settings for the current session ie the SQL studio manager session. The vb.net sqltransaction is running in a different session with a different isolation level.